# Exclude specific columns in select query in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, select

I want to select 15 columns from a table of 20 columns.
Is there a way to exclude those 5 columns instead of specifying other 15 columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible, and it is not such a good idea. What if your columns change later? Than your results will not correspond to your objects. If your question comes from plain laziness than you probably should reconsider.

Comment: This is possible: [check this answer out.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365972/how-can-i-select-from-a-table-in-mysql-but-omit-certain-columns/13808457#13808457) Though it still may not be a good idea if your columns changing creates a possibility of something breaking.

Comment: If the columns change later he will always have to change the query either way. Actually, for the query itself, it's 3 times as likely he won't have to change it; just have to take care of the treatment of the data afterwards, if it's not a dynamic thing.

Answer (score 3):

No, you either have to select them all (*) or list the 15.

Answer (score 2):

Create a view containing only the columns you'd like to get.

Answer (score 0):

Include 15 columns than excluding 5. It is a standard practice too.

(Also try to avoid *, it is not standard eventhough it works)