# How can I "select *" from a table in MySQL but omit certain columns?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the following columns:

```
id,name,age,surname,lastname,catgory,active
```

Instead of: `SELECT name,age,surname,lastname,catgory FROM table`

How can I make something like this: `SELECT * FROM table [but not select id,active]`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select all columns except one in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122/select-all-columns-except-one-in-mysql)

Comment: @tstenner Yes, I believe that this is a duplicate of the one you linked to. While this one is unanswered I believe this one has the better and more accurate [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13808457/1874069) given by donl.

Answer (score 20):

While many say it is best practice to explicitly list every column you want returned, there are situations where you might want to save time and omit certain columns from the results (e.g. testing). Below I have given two options that solve this problem.

**1. Create a Function** that retrieves all of the desired column names: ( I created a schema called functions to hold this function)

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` FUNCTION `getTableColumns`(_schemaName varchar(100), _tableName varchar(100), _omitColumns varchar(200)) RETURNS varchar(5000) CHARSET latin1
BEGIN
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME) FROM information_schema.columns 
    WHERE table_schema = _schemaName AND table_name = _tableName AND FIND_IN_SET(COLUMN_NAME,_omitColumns) = 0 ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION;
END
```

Create and execute select statement:

```
SET @sql = concat('SELECT ', (SELECT 
functions.getTableColumns('test', 'employees', 'age,dateOfHire')), ' FROM test.employees'); 
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt1;
```

**2. OR without writing a function you could:**

```
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT ', (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME) FROM 
information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema = 'test' AND table_name = 
'employees' AND column_name NOT IN ('age', 'dateOfHire')), 
' from test.eployees');  
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt1;
```

*Replace test with your own schema name

**Replace employees with your own table name

***Replace age,dateOfHire with the columns you want to omit (you can leave it blank to return all columns or just enter one column name to omit)

** **You can adjust the lengths of the varchars in the function to meet your needs

Comment: Don't forget to increase the group_concat_max_len, your columns may get cut off. SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 20480

Comment: If you test this sql, you'll likely want to add some `LIMIT` for the test. E.g. `' from test.employees LIMIT 100'`. E.g. to display in phpmyadmin - without a limit, this will timeout on a large table, preparing it for display. Then remove that limit for the final processing.

Comment: It may be useful to store the result into a table. For example, I do this to export a table without its ID (by exporting the temptable instead). `SET @sql = CONCAT('CREATE TABLE temptable SELECT '...`

Answer (score 8):

The only way to do that that I know if is to enumerate each column you do want... no negative filters that I'm aware of.

```
select name, age, surname, lastname, category from table
```

Answer (score 3):

You are too advanced.

The only data language that I have seen that supports your syntax is the Tutorial D language with its "...ALL BUT ..." construct.

See the Tutorial D references in the [The Third Manifesto](https://www.dcs.warwick.ac.uk/%7Ehugh/TTM/reference_material.html)

There are some reference implementations available, but mostly for teaching purposes.

Comment: The link is inactive now. Can you updated it?

Answer (score 2):

you can't do that, sorry. Actually you shouln't have done it if you could - specifying these things explicitly is always better, assume other developer adds new field and your application will fail

Answer (score 1):

Unless there's some special extension in MySql you cannot do that. You either get all, or have to explicitly state what you want. It is best practice to always name columns, as this will not alter the query behaviour even if the underlying table changes.

Answer (score 1):

There is no SQL syntax to support:

```
select * from table but not select id,active
```

If you want all but one or more columns, you have to explicitly define the list of columns you want.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be using select * anyway. Enumerate the columns you want and only the columns you want, that is the best practice.

Answer (score 1):

```
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT ',
    (SELECT REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME), '<columns_to_delete>,', '')
       FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
       WHERE TABLE_NAME = '<table>'
         AND TABLE_SCHEMA = '<database>'),
     ' FROM <table>');

PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt1;
```

Comment: When adding an answer to an older question that already has answers, please explain what is different about your answer, and under what circumstances your answer might be preferable. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain you can't.  Probably the best way I can think of is to create `SELECT name, age, surname, lastname, category FROM table` as a view, then just `SELECT * FROM view`.  I prefer to always select from a view anyway.

However, as others have pointed out, if another column gets added to the view your application could fail.  On some systems as well (PostgreSQL is a candidate) you cannot alter the table without first dropping the view so it becomes a bit cumbersome.

Answer (score 0):

If the reason is to avoid column duplication error without having to specify a long list of columns:

1. temporarily change the name of column that is a duplicate to enable the view to be created.
2. delete the duplicate column from the select and save view
3. rename the changed column name

If the reason is simply to omit a one or more columns:

1. create view and delete column/s from select