# Select specific columns, along with the rest

Tags: mysql

I have a table with a lot of columns. Some of these are `DATETIME`, which I turn into Unix timestamps with `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`. So I don't have to type out all the other columns I want from the table, is there a way of doing something like:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t.start) AS start,
       UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t.end) AS end,
       t.theOtherColumns
FROM table t
```

Where `t.theOtherColumns` is the rest of the columns in the table. To explain further; I want to select all the columns from the table, perform operations on some of them, but not type out each column name into the query.

When I do, say,

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t.start) AS start,
       UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t.end) AS end,
       t.theOtherColumns
FROM table t
```

It selects `start` and `end` twice. I only want to return the `start` and `end` columns from `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`, and exclude those columns from the `t.*` set.

Comment: @Zoltan - But that will bring back `t,start` and `t.end` also. The answer to this question is "No" BTW

Comment: Ok I see. I do not hink it is possible then...

Comment: Ok thanks for that. Worth an ask, though.

Comment: @Jam - You can of course create a `View` if this is a repetitive need though.

Comment: Or you can just remove those extra values server side with whatever programming language you are using to fetch the data.

Comment: Though just to be clear I am not recommending the use of `*`. The function of the `view` would be to avoid keep having to write `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t.start) AS start, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t.end) AS end ...`

Comment: Thanks for all your comments. I'll just stick to typing each one out - it's only for one, possibly two queries anyway.

Comment: @JamWaffles take a look at [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13880100/1639910) as it should give the results this question was looking for. If you think it is a more accurate answer I would suggest you marking it as the answer so that other users can more readily find it. I know it has been a while since you have asked this question but I hope that my answer can help you and others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is a way to do this as you suggested, but you can do this

```
SELECT t.*, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t.start) AS start, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t.end) as end ...
```

Comment: There is a way this can be done. [See my answer below.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13880100/1639910)

Answer (score 5):

What you can do is use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13808457/1639910) to help build the results you want.

A possible solution would look like

```
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t.start) AS start, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t.end) as end,', (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME) FROM 
information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema = 'test' AND table_name = 
't' AND column_name NOT IN ('start', 'end')), 
' from test.t');  
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt1;
```

*Replace test with the name of the schema that contains your table t.

Answer (score 4):

Try t.*  it works under Oracle.