# How to SELECT all columns from a table (except a few)?

Tags: mysql

I want to display the records from a table, except a few columns. The table has 94 columns in it and I want to view all of them except 5. Is that possible? If so, please let me know how?

I know I could select the required columns by specifying them. But I want to omit 5 columns out of 94. It is always better to omit 5 than specifying 89?

I googled but I did not get any idea to do this. So I just want to give last try here!

Comment: Not possible I'm afraid. see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365972/how-can-i-select-from-a-table-in-mysql-but-omit-certain-columns

Comment: Thanks Mark..! Even I never heard of it.But just to know whether it is possible or not??

Comment: @Chella: Mark just answered that question.

Comment: where does he answered??

Comment: Just get them all, translate the matrix, remove the columns... or loop through and remove.

Comment: What is your use case? It is possible a static [view](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html) might help. But .. all depends on "why" you need to do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
$Database_Name="database_example";
$table_example="table_example";
$result = mysql_query("select column_name from information_schema.columns where table_schema = '$Database_Name' and table_name='$table_example' AND column_name NOT IN ('Col89', 'col90','col91','col92', 'col93','col94')");

if (!$result) { 
    die('Invalid request : ' . mysql_error());
}

$SQL="SELECT ";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {   
    foreach($row as $ColonneName)
        $SQL.=$ColonneName.",";
}   

$SQL=rtrim($SQL, ",")." FROM _table_example";

    echo $SQL;
```

Comment: It just display columns,But I want to display all the records inside a table

Comment: GOod work..I appreciate..! But I asked you a query, but you have given me PHP code..Any way Thank you HOurai..!

Comment: You can't do it only with the `SQL`, you have to generate your required SQL with `PHP`(Without writing the full column names manually). But i don't understand why someone votedown my post :(