# MySQL - Extract all data without some field?

Tags: mysql

I got a table (called users) with n column ( n= one billion columns) like this:

**id, email,username,...,...,...,..col_n.**

I want to show all data exclusion id, email with the only Select query.
i don't want to type all field what i want.

How can i do that?

For example:
Table users:

```
+--------+----------+------------+-----------+
| userid | username | password   | privilege |
+--------+----------+------------+-----------+
|      1 | user1    | password   |         1 |
|      2 | david    | goodboy    |         1 |
|      3 | admin    | mastermold |         5 |
|      4 | user4    | password4  |         1 |
|      5 | user5    | password5  |         2 |
|      6 | user6    | password6  |         1 |
|      7 | user7    | password7  |         1 |
+--------+----------+------------+-----------+
```

The result after run query like this:

```
+--------+----------+
| userid | username |
+--------+----------+
|      1 | user1    |
|      2 | david    |
|      3 | admin    |
|      4 | user4    |
|      5 | user5    |
|      6 | user6    |
|      7 | user7    |
+--------+----------+
```

My problem: my table have one billion fields and i have to use the only one select query.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL exclude a column using SELECT \* \[except columnA\] FROM tableA?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/729197/sql-exclude-a-column-using-select-except-columna-from-tablea)

Comment: Also possible duplicate of: [How can I “select *” from a table in MySQL but omit certain columns?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365972/how-can-i-select-from-a-table-in-mysql-but-omit-certain-columns/13808457#13808457)

Comment: @ Jacob Budin. yes, that is my mean

Comment: My problem: Only using one query

Answer (score 0):

One solution is the following. This may not be much efficient but you can try this.

Create a `TEMPORARY TABLE` and drop `id` and `email` from it and use it for query.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_users SELECT * FROM users;
ALTER TABLE temp_users DROP id,email;
SELECT * FROM temp_users;
```

Comment: @ Sabin Jose. Problem: I have to use the only one select query. Your solution is 3 query