# On error use information_schema in MySql function

Tags: mysql

Can you tell me what's wrong with this MySQL function?

I followed the link [How can I “select *” from a table in MySQL but omit certain columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365972/how-can-i-select-from-a-table-in-mysql-but-omit-certain-columns/13808457#13808457)to define a function in MySQL. But I got an error "no database selected".

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION getTableColumns(_schemaName varchar(100), _tableName varchar(100), _omitColumns varchar(200)) RETURNS varchar(5000)
BEGIN
    SELECT REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME), '_omitColumns,', '')
    FROM information_schema.columns 
    WHERE table_schema = _schemaName AND table_name = _tableName
    INTO results;
    RETURN results;
END$$

Error Code: 1046. No database selected Select the default DB to be used by double-clicking its name in the SCHEMAS list in the sidebar.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add database name with function name

```
your_database_name.getTableColumns(......
```

Comment: You are right! Thanks! Is it possible to have a global function across databases?

Comment: No function are always under some database but if you want to use shared function you can use [comman schema] (http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/50678/mysql-possibility-to-create-global-routines-stored-procedures-and-or-functions)